# Best Professional Video editor for Linux equivalent to Sony Vegas Pro?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, sony, video-editor, openshot

I have recently moved onto Linux especially Ubuntu, and I'm a video freak, I love editing videos for my youtube channel, Vimeo, Plex, etc and since I'm new to this Open Source World, I cannot decide which one should I choose?

I had done a search on Google which presented me with Pitvi, Open Shot and such editors but is there any video editor in Linux World equivalent to Sony Vegas video editor? (For Professional Use)

Comment: Uou might try asking this question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try Cinelerra.

Cinelerra is the most advanced non-linear video editor and compositor for Linux. Cinelerra also includes a video compositing engine, allowing the user to perform common compositing operations such as keying and mattes.<sup>[Cinelerra](http://www.heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php)</sup>

To download click [here](http://www.heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php#download). (Edit: or install on 12.04 with the following commands.)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

Also you can try [OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/).

OpenShot has many great features, such as trimming and arranging videos, adjusting audio levels, transitions between videos, compositing multiple layers of video, chroma-key / green screen effect, and support of most formats and codecs.

What really sets OpenShot apart from other video editors is the easy-to-use user interface.<sup>[OpenShot](http://www.openshot.org/)</sup>

To install OpenShot, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openshot.developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openshot openshot-doc
```

Answer (score 11):

[**Kdenlive**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kdenlive/)

[image: Install via the software center]

One of most Fascinating application can be found on Ubuntu for Free.

It can do all most all the Functions that can commercially available famous applications do.

Input and output with many formats.

Can create Creative Overlays including Titles, Headers etc.

Have many functions for Tracks.

Many video and  audio Effects and Transitions.

Can Do Video capture using External Camera, Webcam or Screen Capture.

[image]

You can also install in Terminal with:

```
sudo apt-get install kdenlive kdenlive-data
```

Comment: I tried all the apps above and found that Kdenlive is the best, simplest, featurefull, etc.. Highly recommend!

Comment: kdenlive is really unstable, don't recommend it

Comment: seems pretty stable to me in 2018

Answer (score 3):

You can also try [Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com).

Another great option is Blender. Here is a good [Video Sequence Editor Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIZOWRDICIZ2WCFapHHYLPv).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to take a look at Shotcut (http://shotcut.org/bin/view/Shotcut | http://www.shotcut.org/ | http://www.shotcutapp.com/). Shotcut is still in heavy active development, but it is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Sony Vegas, I suggest you first try running it in Wine. Wine is a compatibility layer for Windows - basically it means you can run Windows programs as if they were Ubuntu apps - without a virtual desktop. The downside is that it hardly works with anything, but there are a few programs it works with if you don't want to install Virtualbox to use Windows apps. Search 'Wine' in the software center, then just download your Sony Vegas .exe file, and double-click it. It'll open in Wine!

Comment: why not just use windows (dual boot) instead of a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Lightworks and Piranha also works on Linux.

Two high-end non-linear video editors are made by IFX for Linux:

- Piranha ( http://ifxsoftware.com/products/piranha );
- and Ant ( http://ifxsoftware.com/ant ).

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Ubuntu Studio, It is built exactly for what you require, it comes with nearly everything you need for running your own Television station. Animation, Sound editing, Video, Photography, web publishing the works.

[UbuntuStudio](https://ubuntustudio.org/tour/video/)