# Tool for automating video splicing at slide transitions?

Tags: software-recommendation, video

I've got a bunch of hour-long videos I want to split out into 5-10 minute pieces.  So far I've simply used the openshot video editor to identify good splice points, and the blazingly fast avconv command-line program to copy out the actual audio and video without changing any formats or codecs.  Then it is easy to upload that to youtube via the google command-line tool.

But I'm looking for something to help automatically find the right splice points.  The video is mostly static slides with some real-time handwriting going on.  So e.g. a script that would process the video and give me timestamps for the major video transitions (slide transitions) would help a lot, especially if it could then back up and go forward from those transitions to eliminate silence.

Is something like that available?
Are other fast/easy video editing pipelines for this sort of work out there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **Kdenlive**. What you need to do is maximize the Timeline. Then you can see the each frame of the video. There is Installation guide in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377367/164718)

Comment: I don't want to manually figure out where the transitions are.  Can kdenlive analyze the video and automatically suggest timestamps which might be good transitions?  They're pretty clear transitions (e.g. a video of a slide show, the only big changes being between one slide and the next, though some of the time someone is writing on the slides you see the writing, but not the person)

Comment: Ok. I was able learn something new from you. Better.