# Which video cutting software runs under Linux/Wine

Tags: wine, video-editor

I know this actually might not belong here. But this is a Question Im asking myself since months.

I need a "better" video cutting software. I already tried everything opensource available, but i need a better one. Do you know any good Linux software or do you know which commercial programms run under wine?

(I would use programms similar to the Magic video deluxe or similar if I would know, if they run without problems under wine.)

Comment: This answer might be helpful.http://askubuntu.com/questions/357196/best-professional-video-editor-for-linux-equivalent-to-sony-vegas-pro

Comment: What do you mean by 'better'? What have you tried, and what was the problem with what you tried so far?

Comment: I have almost tried "every" i did fid over google and so on. But I haven't been statisfied till now.

Comment: But you are unwilling to say what you have found on google? For now your question sounds like "Please read my mind and tell me what i need to know!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is what works best for me if you need a bit more a professional program.

Answer (score 0):

You can install **[Cinelerra](http://heroinewarrior.com/cinelerra.php)**.

As seen on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinelerra), **Cinelerra** is a video editing and compositing software package.

It is designed for the GNU/Linux operating system.

Install it by adding the community repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinelerra-cv
```

Its UI is more complicated than other opensource video editors, but it does the job...  :)

Comment: sounds good: but when i try to install it I get following message: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinelerra-cv : Depends: libquicktimecine-cv (= 1:2.2.git.20140801-0~ppa3~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed"

Comment: it worked, as i used the download link over the download link you posted on [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/357196/best-professional-video-editor-for-linux-equivalent-to-sony-vegas-pro)

Comment: but i don't know if cinelerra is the right thing for my purposes. Its crashing when I try to open just 7 pictures

Comment: no comments on this?